# move_uploaded_file doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php

I'm doing an examination system using PHP. I'm trying to add questions with images and move the image to a designated folder for retrieving purposes. I have the following code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT q_category, q_image, q_question, q_correct, q_answer2,     q_answer3, q_answer4 FROM tblquestions WHERE q_question = "' . $question . '"';

$retval = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
if(!$retval)
{
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $cat = $row1['q_category'];
    $quest = $row1['q_question'];
    $image = $row1['q_image'];
    $correct = $row1['q_correct'];
    $ans2 = $row1['q_answer2'];
    $ans3 = $row1['q_answer3'];
    $ans4 = $row1['q_answer4'];

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td colspan="2"><div class="selectText" align="center">Edit     Questions</div></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Category</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="txtCategory" value = "' . $cat . '"   size="38"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Question</td>';
    echo '<td><textarea rows="4" cols="34" name="txtQuestion" id="txtQuestion"  class="addNew">' . $quest . '</textarea>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Image</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="file" rows="4" cols="28" name="txtImage"  id="txtImage" class="addNew"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Correct Answer</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="txtCorrect" value = "' . $correct . '"  size="38"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Answer 2</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="txtChoice2" value = "' . $ans2 . '"  size="38"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Answer 3</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="txtChoice3" value = "' . $ans3 . '" size="38"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Answer 4</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="txtChoice4" value = "' . $ans4 . '" size="38"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="hiddenQuestion" value = "' . $question .  '">';
}

if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $hiddenQuestion = $_POST['hiddenQuestion'];
    $addCategory = $_POST['txtCategory'];
    $addQuestion = $_POST['txtQuestion'];
    $addCorrect = $_POST['txtCorrect'];
    $addChoice2 = $_POST['txtChoice2'];
    $addChoice3 = $_POST['txtChoice3'];
    $addChoice4 = $_POST['txtChoice4'];

    $filetmp = $_FILES['txtImage']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $_FILES['txtImage']['name'];
    $filepath = "questionImages/".$filename;

    move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);
```

After I click submit, the $filename is empty in the database and the move_uploaded_file doesn't work. If I change $filename = $_FILES['txtImage']['name'] to $filename = $_POST['txtImage'], it adds the the name to the database but still the move_uploaded file doesn't work.

**QUESTION**
I'm thinking that there is something wrong with my $filetmp and $filename. Can anyone point out what's wrong in my code? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does the function `is_uploaded_file()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) return?

Comment: I think the problem might be that you don't have a form, for you to be able to upload file you need a form and set `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Are those `input` elements contained in a `form` element having the attributes`method="post"` and `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? Does your form contain an `input` with attributes `type="submit"` and `name="submit1"`? If any of these doesn't happen, that is the cause of the failure of your code.

Comment: Yes I have a form but i don't have enctype="multipart/form-data". I tried and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Why is my question put on-hold as off topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$filename` and `$filetype` seems ok.

Check in your upload form whether you included `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Also include your form code in the question.

Comment: That's more suitable to be a comment, but I understand why you don't comment in. But also, it was already said in a comment. And you should wrap the value between double-quotes.

Comment: Didn't notice.. :P You are sharp.. :)

Comment: I just do my best to help. But since the O.P. didn't said a word for so long, I would assume that this question was just a bait to get any feedback.

Comment: I'm sorry i was able to go online just now. I tried adding enctype="multipart/form-data" and it worked. Thanks guys :)